# org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role using JpaRepository interface

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm getting the following exception:

`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role:`

I understand why it's happening. I am `LAZY-loading` collections within my entity, and when I try to `get` one of them, the Session is already closed. I do not wish to use load `EAGER-ly`

Since I am simply extending `JpaRepository`, I don't manually manage my Session; so I read that I can fix the issue by annotating `@Transactional` to the calling method. After it didn't seem to work, I tried putting it in multiple places (see code below), still to no avail.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

**Calling code**

```
//@Transactional ***I TRIED PUTTING IT HERE***
public void run() {

    MyParent myParent = myParentRepository.findByName("testName");
    myParent.getChildren(); // fails here
}
```

**MyParentRepository.class**

```
@Repository
public interface MyParentRepository extends JpaRepository<MyParent, Long> {

    //@Transactional ***I TRIED PUTTING IT HERE***
    MyParent findByName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

**MyParent.class**

```
@Entity
public class MyParent {

    // some fields

    @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<MyChild> children;

    public List<MyChild> getChildren() {
        return this.children;
    }
}
```

**MyChild.class**

```
@Entity
public class MyChild {

    // some fields

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private MyParent parent;
}
```

Comment: Annotating the calling method - here `run` - with `@Transactional` is the correct way. Now it all depends on how you initialize `myParentRepository`!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose This comment put me on the right path. I `inject` the repository. However, I have a "wrapper" `factory` which then instantiates another class and passes it the injected `MyParentRepository` instance (I wrapped Spring on an existing Java application). Injecting it directly without that wrapper fixed it. Thanks